# Usage of "all" or "all of"

Tags: word-usage

Which one of the following constructs is better or correct, and **why**? Btw, the meaning of the two is the same, right?

- The customer's all products...
- All of the customer's products...

Comment: Did you get the first example from anywhere in particular?

Comment: The first one is _incorrect_, because it is not a valid use of _all_.

Answer (score 1):

The second is not just better - the first is incorrect. If you need to start with *the customer's*, then you'll need something like

- the customer's products

This is enough; this already refers to all of them.

Mostly just to help you understand, if for some reason you really want to stress that it is all of the customer's products, but you still want to start off with *the customer's*, you could use

- the customer's collection of products
- the customer's selection of products

You could alternately say "set of products", which could sound strange in some situations.  Likewise, *sack, pile, group, box*, etc., if they are in any of those things.

Comment: I think that "the customer's selection of products" might still be ambiguous if they have additional products that they haven't selected - it can refer to a selected subset of their total set of products.